# Spark Connection refused for BlockManager process

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, connection-timeout, resourcemanager, connection-refused

I have a 7 node cluster setup on CentOS VMs in on-prem fashion.
Earlier the VMs were co-located and everything used to work fine, but since yesterday as the VMs have been spread across the data centre (But in same rack), I am facing `Connection refused` and `IOException: Failed to connect to` errors.

Logs:

```
2019-05-24 03:33:37 INFO  TorrentBroadcast:54 - Started reading broadcast variable 6
2019-05-24 03:33:37 ERROR RetryingBlockFetcher:143 - Exception while beginning fetch of 1 outstanding blocks 
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to <HOST/IP>:38000
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:245)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:187)
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService$$anon$2.createAndStart(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.fetchAllOutstanding(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:141)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.start(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:121)
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService.fetchBlocks(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.network.BlockTransferService.fetchBlockSync(BlockTransferService.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getRemoteBytes(BlockManager.scala:693)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply$mcVI$sp(TorrentBroadcast.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:151)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:231)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1347)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.readBroadcastBlock(TorrentBroadcast.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value$lzycompute(TorrentBroadcast.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value(TorrentBroadcast.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.getValue(TorrentBroadcast.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast.value(Broadcast.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text.TextFileFormat$$anonfun$readToUnsafeMem$1.apply(TextFileFormat.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text.TextFileFormat$$anonfun$readToUnsafeMem$1.apply(TextFileFormat.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileScanRDD$$anon$$readCurrentFile(FileScanRDD.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:461)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:461)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.aggregate(TraversableOnce.scala:214)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.aggregate(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$aggregate$1$$anonfun$21.apply(RDD.scala:1122)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$aggregate$1$$anonfun$21.apply(RDD.scala:1122)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:2130)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:2130)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: <HOST/IP>:38000
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:323)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:633)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    ... 11 more
2019-05-24 03:33:37 INFO  RetryingBlockFetcher:164 - Retrying fetch (1/3) for 1 outstanding blocks after 5000 ms
2019-05-24 03:33:42 ERROR RetryingBlockFetcher:143 - Exception while beginning fetch of 1 outstanding blocks (after 1 retries)
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to <HOST/IP>:38000
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:245)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:187)
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService$$anon$2.createAndStart(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.fetchAllOutstanding(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:141)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.lambda$initiateRetry$0(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:169)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: <HOST/IP>:38000
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:323)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:633)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    ... 11 more
2019-05-24 03:33:42 INFO  RetryingBlockFetcher:164 - Retrying fetch (2/3) for 1 outstanding blocks after 5000 ms
2019-05-24 03:33:47 ERROR RetryingBlockFetcher:143 - Exception while beginning fetch of 1 outstanding blocks (after 2 retries)
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to <HOST/IP>:38000
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:245)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:187)
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService$$anon$2.createAndStart(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.fetchAllOutstanding(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:141)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.lambda$initiateRetry$0(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:169)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: <HOST/IP>:38000
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:323)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:633)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    ... 11 more
```

My theory is because the VMs have been spread, there may be delay in their communication and that delay may be overshooting the timeout and hence causing the connection refused or timeouts? Will it be correct to think that ways?

If not, what could be the issue here?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi! Is your VM visible to all your cluster machines? Have you freed your VM ports to allow access by your cluster machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.
BlockManager service was running on 127.0.0.1 because of recent change to VMs.
Fixed that and spark cluster was back to being awsome!